# How to drive a stepper motor, by having it go even steps forward and odd steps back?

Tags: motor, stepper

I have a question about driving a stepper motor back and forward. Basically I want it to do a total of 24 steps (12 forward and 12 back) but I don't want to repeat the same steps when coming back.

So 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 (step numbers) forward and 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 (step numbers) backwards.

Here is the code I have at the moment and I just cannot get the motor to drive properly.

EDIT: It goes 6 times 2 steps forward, then 5 times backwards and after that it starts to just jerk around. What I want it to do is to go 6 times 2 steps forward (so step 2, step 4, step 6, step 8, step 10, 12) and then come back but fill in the odd steps (step 11, step 9, step 7, step 5, step 3, step 1 and step 0). The idea is that then it doesn't just overlap when going forwards and backwards.

```
#include <Stepper.h>
#include <TimerOne.h> 

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  

Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int backwardsCount = 0;
int stepCount = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Timer1.initialize(2000);         
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);  
}

void callback(){
  if(stepCount < 12) {
    myStepper.step(2);
    stepCount += 2;
  } else if(stepCount == 12) {
    myStepper.step(-1);
    backwardsCount = 11;
    stepCount += 1;
  }
  if(backwardsCount > 1) {
    myStepper.step(-2);
    backwardsCount -= 2;
  } else if(backwardsCount == 1) {
    myStepper.step(-1);
    stepCount = 0;
    backwardsCount = 0;
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to implement this as a small state machine. Moreover, why doesn't it do what you want? What do you expect it to do and what does it do in reality?

Comment: I added it to the edit part in the description :)

Comment: Changing `if(backwardsCount > 1){` to `else if(backwardsCount > 1){` would fix the 5 instead of 6 "steps" back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.  A rotational motor must pass through all intermediate angles of rotation, so the goal is impossible.  You could change the points at which the motor *pauses* for a dwell time, but if that is your goal then you need to write the question to say so, and then not abandon it for four months.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried to fix a couple of things from your code.

First of all I implemented a small state machine with two states: going forwards and going backwards. Normally you advance by 2 steps, but when you switch state you go directly to 0 or 11. In my opinion this is the most correct way to handle this problem.

Then I modified the way you trigger a movement. I totally dislike interrupts, specifically when not needed like in this case (at least in my opinion). I used the usual approach with `millis()`. Please note, however, that I had to put 2 milliseconds as period, but I think this was a mistake from your side (I think you wanted 2 seconds). If this is the case, write `const uint16_t moveStepMs = 2000;` instead of `const uint16_t moveStepMs = 2;`. If you want to keep the 2ms, please be aware that `2ms * 6 = 12ms`, so it will go back and forth in about 25ms. This means it is too fast for you to see anything (and probably also for the motor to move).

Here is the code. I hope it is clear; I tested it online, but there wasn't a stepper in the simulator so I just used some LEDs (I think it works, anyway).

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  

Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2, 3, 4, 5);

const byte State_MovingForw = 1;
const byte State_MovingBack = 2;

byte currentState;
int8_t position; // Note: max 127 for position

const uint16_t moveStepMs = 2;
unsigned long prevMillis;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    prevMillis = millis() - moveStepMs;
    currentState = 0; // Invalid, so it will trigger a change
}

void executeStep(int8_t numOfSteps)
{
    myStepper.step(numOfSteps);
    position += numOfSteps;
}

void loop() {
    if ((millis() - prevMillis) > moveStepMs)
    {
        prevMillis += moveStepMs;
        byte nextState = currentState;

        // Check for a state change
        switch (currentState)
        {
        case State_MovingForw:
            if (position >= 12)
                nextState = State_MovingBack;
            break;
        case State_MovingBack:
            if (position <= 1)
                nextState = State_MovingForw;
            break;
        default:
            nextState = State_MovingForw;
        }

        if (nextState != currentState)
        {
            // Exit condition: what to do when exiting from one state
            switch (currentState)
            {
            case State_MovingForw:
                executeStep(0 - position); // Reset position to 0
                break;
            case State_MovingBack:
                executeStep(11 - position); // Reset position to 11
                break;
            }

            // Advance to next state
            currentState = nextState;
        }
        else
        {
            // no state change (so move to the next value)
            switch (currentState)
            {
            case State_MovingForw:
                executeStep(2); // Move two steps forwards
                break;
            case State_MovingBack:
                executeStep(-2); // Move two steps backwards
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I do want the shaft to step every 2 ms because the idea is to quickly move a mirror attached to the shaft that has a laserbeam pointed on it, creating an illusion like there are multiple laserbeams. I have already tried just stepping 12 steps forward and 12 steps back and the motor can handle that kind of speed. The problem was however that the laserbeams didnt match up and they got doubled. I want to have exactly 12 laserbeams. I used a timer because I need to also control the laser (turn off when the motor is stepping and on when it is still).

Comment: Ok, but I think you will need the motor to arrive at the desired position. Maybe this is the issue you are seeing: you are firing the laser when the motor is still moving

Comment: Well the motor wasnt moving properly, it actually worked when I used the 'setspeed()' command but that command conflicts with TimerOne for some reason so the timer won't work then. However I will try your and let you know of the result :). Thanks in advance already!

Comment: @Mr.Owels if this answer "answered" your question please mark it as accepted, or the community bot will think it is still unanswered and continue pushing it to the homepage